# Get number of week by given date and day of week

Tags: calendar-computations

Is there a formula to get the number of week by a given date and day of week

for example Oct 15, 2014 wed. how do i get what number of week is it?

Comment: Do you mean the number of the week within the year?

Comment: ya number of the week within the year!